# Lucene.net 2.9.2 NumericField sort

Tags: lucene.net

Can anyone verify if the latest Lucene.net 2.9.2 can sort (and reverse sort) NumericField? I am sort of stumped, expecially with the reverse sort :(

Answer (score 0):

I also get into the same problem today, the below code is working after troubleshooting for some time.

```
TopDocs matches = searcher.Search(query, null, 10, new Sort(new SortField("id", SortField.INT, true)));
```

This is important `SortField.INT`, otherwise the sorting in the integer field is not working.